# Why is the following for loop not printing anything?

Tags: coffeescript

```
ages = {paul: 11, rick: 7 }

for n,a in ages
  console.log("names: #{n}, ages: #{a}")
```

So nothing is being printed in the console. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That translates into the following JavaScript:

```
var a, ages, n, _i, _len;

ages = {
  paul: 11,
  rick: 7
};

for (a = _i = 0, _len = ages.length; _i < _len; a = ++_i) {
  n = ages[a];
  console.log("names: " + n + ", ages: " + a);
}
```

Note that it's trying to loop through the `ages` object using the `length` property, which doesn't exist.

Change your script so the loop uses `for n,a` **`of`** `ages` syntax instead ([relevant documentation](http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/#loops)), and your code translates into valid JavaScript and prints to the console.

```
var a, ages, n;

ages = {
  paul: 11,
  rick: 7
};

for (n in ages) {
  a = ages[n];
  console.log("names: " + n + ", ages: " + a);
}
```